# Clearing /boot. Advice which files are safe to purge

Tags: package-management, kernel, disk-usage

My boot folder was full. I removed some old kernels. Could you advise which of these can be also purged?

```
gideon@gideon:~$ uname -r
4.10.0-32-generic
gideon@gideon:~$ ls /boot
abi-4.10.0-27-generic         memtest86+.bin
abi-4.10.0-28-generic         memtest86+.elf
abi-4.10.0-30-generic         memtest86+_multiboot.bin
abi-4.10.0-32-generic         System.map-4.10.0-27-generic
config-4.10.0-27-generic      System.map-4.10.0-28-generic
config-4.10.0-28-generic      System.map-4.10.0-30-generic
config-4.10.0-30-generic      System.map-4.10.0-32-generic
config-4.10.0-32-generic      vmlinuz-4.10.0-27-generic
efi                           vmlinuz-4.10.0-27-generic.efi.signed
grub                          vmlinuz-4.10.0-28-generic
initrd.img-4.10.0-27-generic  vmlinuz-4.10.0-28-generic.efi.signed
initrd.img-4.10.0-28-generic  vmlinuz-4.10.0-30-generic
initrd.img-4.10.0-30-generic  vmlinuz-4.10.0-30-generic.efi.signed
initrd.img-4.10.0-32-generic  vmlinuz-4.10.0-32-generic
initrd.img-4.8.0-36-generic   vmlinuz-4.10.0-32-generic.efi.signed
lost+found
```

Comment: All those removed by `sudo apt autoremove` can and will be safely removed. This will be all except the current version and the one before that which is kept as a fallback.

Comment: There is 4.11 available

Comment: @MichaelBay advising OP to run `autoremove` is the best possible answer to this question IMHO. I recommend posting an answer to that effect :)

Comment: Advice, always run the command `sudo apt autoremove` when advised by `apt` I do that often. If you don't then at a point you won't have space for further updates

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RemoveOldKernels